# CMD cipher /e on a folder output "Request not supported"

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell

I've recently discovered `cipher` command on windows-10 command-line.

Now, the problem is when I'm try to execute `cipher /e [directory name]` or `cipher /e [absolute path]`, because I'm always receiving the error `[directory name]: Request not supported.`.

Some useful info:

- I'm running Microsoft Windows 10 Home
- I've executed the command as administrator either on 'cmd' and 'powershell'
- The disk's file system is in 'NTFS'.
- I've gave all the access to all the users in the 'Security' attribute on the interested folder(An empty folder for test purposes).

Could someone give me a hint/suggestion/solution about where the problem could be? Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `cipher /e` on a folder outputs Request not supported.

> I'm running Microsoft Windows 10 Home

`cipher` is **not supported on Home editions of Windows** as it uses the Encrypting File System (EFS).

And:

> EFS is available in all versions of Windows **except the home
>   versions** (see Supported operating systems below) from Windows 2000
>   onwards.
>
> ...
>
> - Windows 2000 Professional, Server, Advanced Server and Datacenter editions
> - Windows XP Professional, also in Tablet PC Edition, Media Center Edition and x64 Edition
> - Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2003 R2, in both x86 and x64 editions
> - Windows Vista Business, Enterprise and Ultimate editions[9]
> - Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate editions
> - Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2
> - Windows 8 and 8.1 Pro and Enterprise editions
> - Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2
> - Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, and Education editions.
> - Windows Server 2016
> - Windows Server 2019

Source [Encrypting File System - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System#Windows)